# Is there a way to create buckets and set CORS only using Javascript(in browser)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cors, aws-sdk

From [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/EnableCorsUsingREST.html) I know that I can set bucket CORS via REST API, but these API calls themselves would meet cross-domain problems if sent from browser. So I wonder if there's a method to manage s3 buckets using javascript only(in browser, without a proxy server)?

Tried and affirmed, test code and result picture below:

```
        AWS.config.region = 'us-east-1';
        AWS.config.accessKeyId = 'YTBGSLU96NCNWPKEY11E';
        AWS.config.secretAccessKey = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'; // not that silly to tell you

        var s3 = new AWS.S3();
        s3.createBucket({
            Bucket: 'test',
            ACL: 'public-read-write'
        }, function(err, data) {
            if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
            else     console.log(data);           // successful response
        })
```

[image: API calls blocked by browser]

Comment: Just checkout the SDK.  https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-browser/

Comment: @mootmoot sample code and result picture updated, please review whether I'm doing it wrong.

Comment: You don't need to show the key configuration part.   You can't simply slap a ACL for S3 CORS, lots of details required.  Please refer this : http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/cors.html